# Как прикрутит анимацию к pipe?

Tags: анимация, angular2, angular, pipes

***app.component.ts***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animateAppear', [

      transition('* <=> *', [
        query(
          ':enter',
          [
            style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-15px)' }),
            stagger(
              '50ms',
              animate(
                '550ms ease-out',
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0px)' })
              )
            )
          ],
          { optional: true }
        ),

        query(':leave', animate('50ms', style({ opacity: 0 })), {
          optional: true
        }),
        query(
          ':leave',
          [
            style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-15px)' }),
            stagger(
              '50ms',
              animate(
                '550ms ease-out',
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0px)' })
              )
            )
          ],
          { optional: true }
        )

      ])


    ])
  ]

})
```

есть pipe который фильтрует текст

***search.pipe.ts***

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(ninjas: any, words: any): any {

    if (words === undefined ) { return ninjas; }

    return ninjas.filter( ninja => {
      return ninja.assocProducts.toLowerCase().includes( words.toLowerCase() );
    });
  }

}
```

я анимировал фильтрацию добавив *@animateAppear*

```
<div class="container" [@animateAppear]='[words]'>
```

***app.component.html***

```
<!--  animation block  -->
<div class="container" [@animateAppear]='[words]'>


      <!--  ngModel input filter Data  -->
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="words">

      <!--  For  -->
      <div *ngFor="let product of products | search:words">

              <!-- Template -->

              <img class="col-md-6" src="{{ 'https:' + product.primaryImageUrl }}" width="50px" height="50px">

              <div class="col-md-6">{{ product.assocProducts }}</div>

      </div>
</div>
```

но это все работает не корректно хотелось бы реализовать следующие ,

когда пользователь вводит текст чтобы отфильтрованные товары которые должны удалиться из DOM `search:words` с начало плавно стали `opacity: 0;` затем 
`height: 0;` а только потом исчезали из DOM, и когда они становились валидные то наоборот сначало `height: *;` а потом `opacity: 1;`,

как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: а зачем вы анимируете родитель если вы хотите анимировать блоки в списке?)

Comment: потому что только так это работает в данном случае и это кстати странно

Comment: вам не нужно анимировать родителя + привязываться каким-то образом к пайпам, пайпы это преобразователи данных, они никоим образом к анимациям не имеют отношения

Comment: я догадываюсь , нужно как то анимировать по событию , вот только по какому

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предлагаю вам пойти таким путем. Давайте ту сложную анимацию `animateAppear` просто выбросим, потому что она ни к селу, ни к городу.

Триггер - это маркер, который биндится к определенному DOM элементу, который нужно анимировать. То есть компилятор натыкается на констукцию `@triggerName` и сразу понимает, что нужно сгенеривать определенный JavaScript код из метаданных, указанных в декораторе в свойстве `animations`.

Анимационные запросы (`query`) используются для доступа к анимациям и состояниям дочерних элементов, например `query('h1:enter', [ анимации ])`. `stagger` - это отдельная тема и довольно таки сложная, применяется она для итеративных анимаций (также предлагаю на этом не зацикливаться).

Нам будет достаточно парочки функций - это `trigger, transition, style, animate`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass'],
  animations: [
    trigger('appear', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({
          height: 0,
          opacity: 0
        }),

        animate('100ms', style({
          height: '100%',
          opacity: 1
        }))
      ]),

      transition(':leave', [
        style({
          height: '100%',
          opacity: 1
        }),

        animate('100ms', style({
          height: 0,
          opacity: 0
        }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

Биндить этот триггер мы будем к элементам, которые рендерятся через директиву `ngIf`:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products | search: words" @appear>
```

`transition` - это, фактически, и есть описание нашей анимации, только для конкретного состояния. Когда элемент проджектнулся в DOM через `Node.prototype.appendChild` - для него вызывается функция [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate). Описывать эту функцию здесь я не буду, вы можете почитать документацию, но интереса ради вы можете поиграться с этой функцией и посмотреть с какими аргументами Angular вызывает ее (чисто в практических целях):

```
const original = HTMLElement.prototype.animate;
HTMLElement.prototype.animate = function() {
  console.log(arguments);
  return original.apply(this, arguments);
};
```